# Deprecated methods in xcode7/swift 2.0

Tags: ios, mobile, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

I am in the middle of updating my app which was built in ios 8 to ios9 by using xcode7/swift 2.0. Like many other people, my app crashed very heavily. The basic concept of my app is to let users to upload videos/images to a certain event. Right now, I am having an error message saying

> object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.9.0)

from parse. I thought it was Parse's error at first but figured out I may have made some dumb mistakes while I was updating codes. If you can take a look at the changes I made and point out the errors I made, it would be super helpful.

I changed following:

```
var outputURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(filename)").stringByAppendingString(".mp4"))
```

to

```
var outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(filename).mp4")
```

I made this change because stringByAppendingString is deprecated now.

Other change i made is:

```
let filename = (outputFileUrl.absoluteString.stringByDeletingPathExtension.lastPathComponent ?? "video") + "-c"
```

to

```
let filename = (outputFileUrl.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent ?? "video") + "-c"
```

I am pretty sure I did right with converting functions. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can point out what I did wrong in those two changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference of the first example is:

- The former syntax creates an NSString object
- The new syntax creates an NSURL object

Either use the URL related API for example instead of `…contentsOfFile` use `…contentsOfURL` or get the path of the URL from the `path` property

```
let outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(filename).mp4").path!
```

The second example returns a string with percent encoded special characters in the former syntax and a string without percent encoding in the new syntax. You might add the percent encoding.

An alternative method to keep the older syntax is to cast the `String` to `NSString` e.g.

```
let filename = (((outputFileUrl.absoluteString as NSString).stringByDeletingPathExtension as NSString).lastPathComponent ?? "video") + "-c"
```

but I recommend to use the URL related API